# Trig Vector Problem- Finding How fast the wind blows

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, vector-analysis, trigonometric-integrals

A planes actual resulting ground speed and direction are 550 mph and N26E. A wind is blowing from the northeast. If the pilot is holding a course of N27E how fast is the wind blowing?

This question came from my Trig/Precalc class and I can't figure it out. We are on a vector unit and just covered Vector Applications

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Does N26E mean "26 degrees East of North"?